# Octopress HTML parsing bug

Tags: jekyll, octopress

I'm sort of updating my Octopress website, and decided to start from a clean install and add my customizations. I'm noticing a buggy behavior that was not there before in how Octopress parses html tags in particular situations.

An example. In the `head` section, I have the following commented out line:

`<!--<link href="{{ root_url }}/favicon.png" rel="icon"> -->`

This should be a perfectly valid commented out line, and works perfectly *except* when there's another html tag within the comment (i.e. `<link ...>`). In the above case, Octopress replaces the `--` at the end of the comment with `&#8211;`, the HTML code for en-dash, with the result that the comment never actually ends when it should.

I found a workaround for this case by using `<-->` for closing the comment tag.

This is also happening in another instance, and I need help with this one. A few of my blog titles have an `<em>` in them, so that when Octopress creates an html for it, the result *should* be, for example:
`<a href="/blog/link/to/post" title="My Title With <em>Emphasized</em> Text">My Title With <em>Emphasized</em> Text</a>`

However, once again, since there's a nested tag here, the actual result is the following:
`<a href="/blog/link/to/post" title="My Title With <em>Emphasized</em> Text&#8221;>My Title With <em>Emphasized</em> Text</a>`

i.e., the closing `"` at the end of the `title` is replaced with `&#8221;`, the HTML code for `"`, with disastrous results.

I can't find a solution or a workaround for this... help!

I found a bug report here, but there doesn't seem to be any activity about this.
https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/1662

Once again, I should emphasize that this is a bug in a more recent build of Octopress (or its dependencies), and was not present in an earlier version that I have been using.

Help! :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, found a solution!

Find the html layout file for your post type, usually here: `/source/_layouts/post.html`, and find this section:

`<p class="meta">
      {% if page.previous.url %}
        <a class="basic-alignment left" href="{{page.previous.url}}" title="Previous Post: {{page.previous.title}}">&laquo; {{page.previous.title}}</a>
      {% endif %}
      {% if page.next.url %}
        <a class="basic-alignment right" href="{{page.next.url}}" title="Next Post: {{page.next.title}}">{{page.next.title}} &raquo;</a>
      {% endif %}
    </p>`

Add `| strip_html` after the two instances of `title`, as follows:

`title="Previous Post: {{page.previous.title | strip_html}}`

and

`title="Next Post: {{page.next.title  | strip_html}}"`

And that's it! Now there's no html inside the title quote, and no issues!